# Angular2: Get dimensions of DOM-Element (without ElementRef)

Tags: dom, angular

I try to get dimensions of a DOM-Element (heigtht/width).
As for security reasons (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html) I don't want to directly acccess the DOM.

Does anyone have some other Idea?

Comment: Why don't your want to use ElementRef?

Comment: As I thought more about it: It doesn't matter. The two reasons to not use it are 1) Security: Which only applies if I modify the DOM Object 2) Server-Side-Rendering: Doesn't apply as I would have to rerender on changes of width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought more about my Question:

Actually accessing the DOM-Element through ElementRef is no security threat in this case, as no (unsafe-)data is injected through it.

If you want to get around using ElementRef (eg. for server side rendering) and want to manipulate a DOM-Element I recommend to look at the Renderer class.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: '<div #myDiv (click)=getElementDimensions(myDiv)>Hello</div>'
})
export class AboutComponent {

  constructor() { }

  getElementDimensions(el: HTMLDivElement) {
    console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect())
  }

}
```